# How To Correctly Install Python On Windows 7 64 Bit?

Tags: python

I am having lots of trouble getting python 2.7.2 to install on my system correctly. I have tried to download the activestate version http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads and it seems to be installed correctly but when I try to run python from my terminal I keep getting this message. 'python' not recognized as internalexternal command, operable program or batch file.

Anyone know how to fix this? I google it and only get the answer for windows XP.

Thanks..

Comment: you have to add the location of the exectuable to your path

Comment: Active State normally installs python correctly in win 7 64 bit (Python 2.6.6 in my case) Maybe you did not run a default (complete) installation?.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Just for reference. I founf the complete instructions on fixing this here as well http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=35044.0

Comment: @Gary Just for reference, the link you refer to contains the same information as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the Python installation directory is in your `PATH` environment variable. I thought that the ActiveState installer did that for you, but in any case, that seems to be the problem here.

You can set the `PATH` enviroment variable in: `View Advanced System Settings -> Enviroment Variables`. Just add python folder at the end of the list (separated with semicolon).

Comment: One thing I wasn't aware of when I started using python is that it also comes with several handy scripts in a subfolder. Add this to your path as well to make them easy to access.